# What is the correct way to store access token from OAuth callback

Tags: java, facebook, oauth, scribe

Here's my working code to get access token on a Facebook User's behalf:

```
@Override
public void receiveCallback() {
    OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
            .provider(FacebookApi.class)
            .apiKey(KEY)
            .apiSecret(SECRET)
            .callback("http://example.com/facebook_oath_callback/")
            .build();
    Verifier verifier = new Verifier(code);
    Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(EMPTY_TOKEN, verifier);
    LOG.info("Got access token: " + accessToken);
}
```

It is able to redirect prior to this code and call this `receiveCallback` method via the `facebook_oath_callback` and is able to get the `accecssToken` properly.

I am thinking of storing this token in this kind of bean

```
class AccessToken {
  String facebookUID; // where to get this?
  String accessToken; 
}
```

However in the context of the callback method, that Facebook called back, there is no facebook UID that we can get to know who's access token is this for? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need another REST call to the Facebook Graph API to "inspect" the access token and in the JSON result from that call there's the `user_id` element that you're looking for. That is described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.3#confirm

You would be interested in the section called "Inspecting access tokens".